# YouTube Streaming with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, youtube

Using the following tutorial to broadcast to YouTube Live. Looks like the stream is working on the Pi end, and even YouTube's account page has a little green light saying that it's receiving data from the device. Perhaps I'm missing some authentication or one other element of this puzzle?

Tutorial here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/live-stream-youtube-raspberry-pi/

CLI here:

`raspivid -o - -t 0 -vf -hf -fps 30 -b 6000000 | avconv -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/[your-secret-key-here]`